# How to edit default Header of the invoice Qweb reports . Odoo 14

Tags: javascript, python, xml, odoo

I am using Odoo 14, I would like to customize the header of 'report_invoice_document'.
I tried to add this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <odoo>
     <data>
       <template id="report_invoice_extend" inherit_id="account.report_invoice_document">
        <t t-call="my_module.external_layout_footer_inherit_cr">
    
        </t>
     </template>
    </data>
 </odoo>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
<template id="external_layout_footer_inherit_cr"
            inherit_id="report.external_layout_footer">
            <xpath expr="//div[@class='footer']" position="replace">
                <div class="footer">
                    <span>Test</span>
                </div>
            </xpath>
        </template>
</odoo>
```

But I got this error :

```
raise ValueError(formatted_message).with_traceback(from_traceback) from from_exception odoo.exceptions.ValidationError: Error while validating view:

Element '<t t-call="my_module.external_layout_footer_inherit_cr">' cannot be located in parent view
```

What's wrong in my code? Please help.

Comment: If you want to make custom header invoice, you must add data-oe-model and data-oe-id in body class.

Comment: @Aung Ko Ko Lin, can you give an example?

Comment: check this out, https://learnopenerp.blogspot.com/2018/10/how-to-add-custom-header-and-footer-in-qweb-reports-in-odoo.html

Comment: also this, https://www.odoo.com/es_ES/forum/ayuda-1/how-to-edit-default-header-footer-of-the-invoice-pdf-reports-160775

Comment: @Obay Abd-Algader, I edited the post , I tried the solution in link , but I got the following error: Element '<t t-call="universal_discount.external_layout_footer_inherit_cr">' cannot be located in parent view

Answer (score 0):

As an example

```html
<div class="article page" t-attf-data-oe-model="account.move" t-attf-data-oe-id="{{o.id}}" t-attf-style="color:{{style.text_color}} !important;font-size:{{int(style.body_font)}}px !important;font-family:{{style.font_family}} !important;">
</div>
```